Are There Techniques for Analyzing Data That Have Predictor Variables That Contain Ranges of Numbers Instead of Single Values?
Are there techniques for analyzing data that have predictor variables that contain ranges of numbers instead of single values? For example, soil samples can be obtained from 0-to-5-cm depths, 5-to-10-cm depths, and 10-to-20-cm depths (note the inconsistency in the width of these ranges too). I could treat these groups as categories, but then I lose information about their positions; I could rank them, but in my example, ranking won't account for the differences in the widths of the ranges.
Thanks so much for the answers. Here are my responses to them.
The midpoint idea makes some sense considering in the soil sampling example I gave the cylinder of soil extracted will be a constant area across its entire length, but if the response variable is (for example) nitrogen concentration, and the nitrogen concentration at the shallowest depth within a depth range is extraordinarily higher than the nitrogen concentration elsewhere in this depth range, the results could be pretty skewed. If the area varied by depth, I could calculate the center of mass of the shape (if it's possible to do that calculation) and use that as the value instead of the midpoint.
There are some things about the random noise idea that I like. Maybe a more accurate way to do it would be to break each category down into small intervals and use the response variable from that category for each of these individual points (which would be values from within the category). In my soil example, I could use the measurement from the 0-to-5-cm depth for 1-, 2-, 3-, and 4-cm depths, I could use the measurement from the 5-to-10-cm depth for 6-, 7-, 8-, and 9-cm depths, and I could use the measurement from the 10-to-20-cm depth for 11-, 12-, 13-, 14-, 15-, 16-, 17-, 18-, and 19-cm depths.
I'm a little skeptical about modeling noise in each category because of the reason I mentioned above (if there is variability within each category due to higher values occurring primarily at one end of the range).
In my example, each category is bounded on both sides, although I can imagine other examples where at least one category is unbounded.
Thanks!

Could you please tell us about your model?  Everything depends on that.  What do you think might depend on sample depth and how?

@whuber - a very simple example would be doing a trend analysis of total organic carbon (the response variable) across different soil depths (the predictor variable).

Right: this is no different than using any such measurement as a predictor in a regression; and all the usual considerations apply concerning variable selection and "feature engineering."  The only potential complication in practice concerns whether (a) the sample supports vary greatly and (b) you are engaged in some kind of kriging or similar resource estimation procedure that needs to account for this "change of support" issue.

One thing you could do is to make each the midpoint of its category, so 0 to 5 becomes 2.5. This is rather unrealistic, but may be good enough.
To get a little more sophisticated, you could add random noise to each of these points, based on a uniform distribution so that the 0 to 5 values can take any value from 0 to 5.
Even more sophisticated, you could look at the overall distribution by categories and use that to pick a distribution for the values within each category. E.g. if the overall distribution looks roughly Normal, that could give you better estimates of how to model the noise in each category. Then, in the 0 to 5 category, 5 would be more likely than 0.
Or you could do all of these and see if it makes much difference.
If your top category is unbounded, you would have to make some additional assumptions.

Thanks for the response! I'm going to update my original question to address some of these options.

AFAIK nobody adds random noise in this context.  These samples reflect different spatial volumes, aka "supports"--the concentrations are usually averages over the entire volume--and are more than adequately represented either by their tops or midpoints in just about any kind of analysis.

@whuber - my concerns about using an end of the range (such as the top) or the midpoint are mentioned in my original post. Would it be better to think about the midpoint as a center of mass of the range? I can imagine a scenario where instead of extracting a perfectly cylindrical column of soil, one may extract a cone of soil, and thus the midpoint wouldn't be the center of mass.

That's fine--go ahead use the CM.  But there's nothing inherently wrong with using tops, bottoms, or any transformation of those values you like.  These issues are common to all regression and indeed to all modeling.

You could use indicator variables for those depth categories. Then the data could be used to tell what relationships can be found. For example, some characteristics could increase or decrease monotonically (not necessarily linearly) with depth; other characteristics could change in a humped way and be at a maximum or minimum at some intermediate depth. The pattern of parameter estimates should be informative either way.
You don't lose information about their positions, because this is part of what you know, and as implied above, you can always plot parameter estimates, predictions, and so forth in the order you know. On the other hand using even midpoint depths, while worth trying, may also make it harder to find nonlinear or non-monotonic relationships.
Contextual information and understanding (e.g. physical, chemical, biological, geological, agronomic or other land use)  may all be valuable.
